# Blazor - How to manager @ref for initial invisible part of a component

Tags: components, blazor

I have a Blazor component who is composed of one div included in an @if directive (IsVisible). The div has an @ref. When the component is rendered, IsVisible is false. My component has a method (Show()) who set IsVisible to true and use the reference to the div. But the reference is always null (no Context and no Id).

```
@if (IsVisible)
{
  <div @ref="MyRef">Bla bla bla</div>
}

@code {
  bool IsVisible = false;
  ElementReference MyRef;
  public void Show()
  {
    IsVisible = true;
    StateHasChanged();
    // here, MyRef has no Context and no Id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of the classic component misconception:  `StateHasChanged` re-renders the component.  NO, it queues a render event onto the Renderer's Queue.  In your code this doesn't happen until the end of `Show` - it's a synchronous block of code, so runs to completion before the Renderer gets any thread time. You are  checking for `MyRef` before it exists.

You need to modify `Show`.

```
    public async Task Show()
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        // Yields and lets the Renderer service it's queue
        await Task.Yield();
        // or await Task.Delay(1);
        // now we exist
        var x = MyRef;
  }
```

Comment: You can't actually be sure that MyRef will be set during the Yield() - it depends on how it's called and what else is going on. (not my dv by the way).

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  I was going to answer the question with a `DivComponent` component controlling show and hide, but decided that didn't directly answer the question.   And yes I agree you could load Show with code that might impact on the Renderer servicing it's queue.

Comment: For future reference, the appropriate place to do things with an ElementReference is in the OnAfterRender[Async] handler.  They're not guaranteed to exist prior to that.